# where do I get sqllite.dll to import into vs.net?

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite

I downloaded a version of sqllite, but when trying to add as reference I got an error.

sqllite3.dll cannot be added, please make sure the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or com component.

Is there a special dll for vs.net that i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [System.Data.Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), which puts a .NET wrapper around the raw SQLite code.

Answer (score 0):

download the sqlite Ado.Net Provider:

The provider was written specifically for ADO.NET 2.0, using all the most recent changes to the ADO.NET framework.  That includes full DbProviderFactory support, automatic distributed transaction enlistment, connection pooling, extensive schema support, Entity Framework support and more.

http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=132486

by using this you have full design time support and the missing declarations are done by VS at design